# Android: Animations

Tags: java, android, animation

Just a quick question to resolve an issue I am having. I am currently trying to stop animations from animating when I leave an activity, these animations are ObjectAnimators and are set to an infinite loop. I have read that if these animations are set to infinite they cannot be stopped, is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `anim.cancel();` in android `onStop()` life cycle;

Comment: would I have to declare my animations inside onStop as well?

Comment: You have to call anim.cancel(); in onStop() method;